# IIS Enable the HTTP Keep-Alive in Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, wmi, keep-alive

The page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183(v=ws.10).aspx explains how to Enable the HTTP Keep-Alive Response Header (IIS 7)

I want to do this in **Powershell** by WMI

It says:

> Use the following WMI classes, methods, or properties to perform this
>   procedure:
>   **HTTPProtocolSection.AllowKeepAlive** property

I've tried:

```
PS > Get-WmiObject -Class HTTPProtocolSection
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WmiObject <<<<  -Class HTTPProtocolSection
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

What's the right way of using this HTTPProtocolSection class and enabling AllowKeepAlive property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To discover class in a particular namespace try this

```
PS c:\>Get-WmiObject -List * "root\webadministration"
```

and to find a match do this

```
PS c:\>Get-WmiObject -List * "root\webadministration" | Where-Object {$_.name -match "Http"}


PS C:\>Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\webadministration" -class HttpProtocolSection | Get-Member

TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\webadministration\HttpProtocolSection

Name                MemberType    Definition
----                ----------    ----------
PSComputerName      AliasProperty PSComputerName = __SERVER
Add                 Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Add(System.String CollectionName, System.Ma...
Clear               Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Clear(System.String CollectionName)
Get                 Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Get(System.String CollectionName, System.St...
Remove              Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Remove(System.String CollectionName, System...
RevertToParent      Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject RevertToParent(System.String PropertyName)
AllowKeepAlive      Property      bool AllowKeepAlive {get;set;}
CustomHeaders       Property      System.Management.ManagementObject#CustomHeaderSettings CustomHeaders {get;set;}
Location            Property      string Location {get;set;}
Path                Property      string Path {get;set;}
RedirectHeaders     Property      System.Management.ManagementObject#RedirectHeaderSettings RedirectHeaders {get;set;}
SectionInformation  Property      System.Management.ManagementObject#SectionInformation SectionInformation {get;set;}
__CLASS             Property      string __CLASS {get;set;}
__DERIVATION        Property      string[] __DERIVATION {get;set;}
__DYNASTY           Property      string __DYNASTY {get;set;}
__GENUS             Property      int __GENUS {get;set;}
__NAMESPACE         Property      string __NAMESPACE {get;set;}
__PATH              Property      string __PATH {get;set;}
__PROPERTY_COUNT    Property      int __PROPERTY_COUNT {get;set;}
__RELPATH           Property      string __RELPATH {get;set;}
__SERVER            Property      string __SERVER {get;set;}
__SUPERCLASS        Property      string __SUPERCLASS {get;set;}
ConvertFromDateTime ScriptMethod  System.Object ConvertFromDateTime();
ConvertToDateTime   ScriptMethod  System.Object ConvertToDateTime();
```

You can then do something like this to get the value of AllowKeepAlive

```
PS C:\> (get-wmiobject -namespace "root\webadministration" -class HttpProtocolSection).AllowKeepAlive 
True

PS C:\>$a = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\webadministration" -class HttpProtocolSection
PS C:\>$a.AllowKeepAlive = $false
PS C:\>$a.Put()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also set it with the `Set-WebConfiguration` cmdlet:

```
Set-WebConfiguration -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST -Value @{allowKeepAlive=$true}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Shay. I ended up using this solution, although it's not WMI based as I asked originally. The only thing to mention here to newbies like me that you need to run: Import-Module WebAdministration. Also, probably the following command is even simpler: Set-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.webServer/httpProtocol" -name allowKeepAlive -value "true"

Comment: Yup, I should have mention Import-Module :)

Comment: I am getting "The property 'AllowKeepAlive' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set." Everything appears to be fine. Thoughts?

AllowKeepAlive      Property      bool AllowKeepAlive {get;set;}